# In iterm how do I show the start time of a command

Tags: iterm2, iterm

I would like to see when I typed a certain command. How do I display this in my terminal prompt?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

On Mac press `shift+cmd+e` and see the times display on the right of the terminal. This time displayed is the time at which you type the last character for a command.

Answer (score 7):

Have no idea why settings in Advanced not works for me.
I managed to make it in Preferences > Profile -> Session -> Show timestamps

[image: settings]

Answer (score 2):

U can Go to Preferences > Advanced > then in Search Box type timestamp
and then enable that its the simplest solution and if u want to customize the terminal prompt then u can refer to this link https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k and for your reference the o/p is in last screenshot

or u can use p10k theme if u are using linux or mac, i dont have any idea about windows

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]